# Measuring cyclomatic complexity of nested s-exp

Tags: regular-expressions, syntax

I would like to measure the Cyclomatic Complexity on a file or a region of elisp code.  By counting the maximum number of nested s-exp.

Comment: You most probably don't want such a regex. What exactly are you trying to do? Please edit your question and add that info: do not add it in a comment.

Comment: The good news is that Lisp programs are Lisp lists, so finding the deepest-nested form is tractable. The trouble is, that won't (necessarily) map directly to cyclomatic complexity, at least not in the sense that I understand the term. The trouble is that where block-nesting in block-structured languages (C, Pascal, Fortran and their multifarious descendants) occurs only* where flow-control constructs are introduced, the same is not true in Lisps, where nesting more often indicates what would be nested/compound operator expressions or simple function/method/procedure calls in other languages.

Comment: * More or less!

Comment: @PhilHudson You are right.  What would be a sensible thing to do for the specific elisp case?  It would be useful to have some measures even though the measure would not correspond to the exact definition of cyclomatic complexity.  For a proper evaluation, I would need to write an actual program than do things as an emacs feature.

Comment: It's a very interesting question. I'm way unqualified to answer it though.